# SQL Joins with TypeORM

Tags: sql, json, typescript, typeorm

This is my current Entity structure:

entity/Ticket.ts

```js
import {Entity, PrimaryColumn, Column, OneToMany, ManyToOne, OneToOne, JoinColumn} from "typeorm";
import { Gym } from "./Gym";
import { TicketInteraction } from "./TicketInteraction";
import { TicketType } from "./TicketType";
import { User } from "./User";

@Entity()
export class Ticket {

    @PrimaryColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @ManyToOne(type => Gym, gym => gym.tickets)
    gym: Gym;

    @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.tickets)
    user: User;

    @ManyToOne(type => TicketType, type => type.tickets)
    type: TicketType;

    @OneToMany(type => TicketInteraction, interactions => interactions.ticket, {
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
    })
    interactions: TicketInteraction[];

    @Column()
    title: string;
}
```

entity/TicketInteraction.ts

```js
import {Entity, PrimaryColumn, Column, ManyToOne} from "typeorm";
import { Ticket } from "./Ticket";
import { User } from "./User";

@Entity()
export class TicketInteraction {

    @PrimaryColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @ManyToOne(type => Ticket, ticket => ticket.interacoes, {
        cascade: true
    })
    ticket: Ticket;

    @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.interactions)
    user: User;

    @Column({ type: 'text' })
    description: string;

    @Column({ type: 'date' })
    date: string;

    @Column({ type: 'time' })
    time: string;
}
```

entity/User.ts

```js
import {Entity, PrimaryColumn, Column, OneToMany, ManyToMany, ManyToOne} from "typeorm";
import { Gym } from "./Academia";
import { Ticket } from "./Ticket";
import { TicketInteracao } from "./TicketInteracao";
import { UserType } from "./UserType";

@Entity()
export class Usuario {

    @PrimaryColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column({ length: 50 })
    name: string;

    @ManyToOne(type => Gym, gym => gym.users, {
        cascade: true
    })
    gym: Gym;

    @ManyToOne(type => UserType, type => type.users, {
        cascade: true
    })
    type: UserType;

    @OneToMany(type => Ticket, tickets => tickets.user)
    tickets: Ticket[];

    @OneToMany(type => TicketInteraction, interactions => interactions.user)
    interactions: TicketInteraction[];
}
```

entity/UserType.ts

```js
import {Entity, PrimaryColumn, Column, OneToMany} from "typeorm";
import { User } from "./User";

@Entity()
export class UserType {

    @PrimaryColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column({ length: 50 })
    description: string;

    @OneToMany(type => User, user => user.type, {
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
    })
    user: User[];
}
```

So, a user contain many tickets and a ticket contain many interactions and these interactions has also a user that created it, I just need a to build a query where I select all the tickets of a user, also the LAST interaction of that ticket, and the user that made that interaction with its type.

I can't build this query, i've tried so many ways and i can't figure out, all i made it so far is select a ticket and its interactions and at most get the user who made it, but in no way can I get the user type. This is my query at the moment:

```js
   let query = createQueryBuilder(Ticket, 'ticket')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('ticket.interacoes', 'ticket_interacao')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('ticket_interacao.usuario', 'usuario')
      .orderBy('ticket_interaction.date', 'DESC')
      .orderBy('ticket_interaction.time', 'DESC')
```

and this is the JSON:

```json
{
 [
   {
     "id": "0b8c5b62-1eb2-4b28-9fb9-97dc680a3c02",
     "title": "Title",
     "interactions": [
       {
         "id": "1e0bc060-ceb7-4722-898a-9bb22685afd0",
         "description": "Description",
         "date": "2021-03-07",
         "time": "18:45:52"
         "user": {
           "id": "0739f286-ecf5-4579-8efe-3062941a5e7f",
           "name": "usuario"
         }
       },
       {
         "id": "188bf283-8a0d-472f-83b9-2755d11016fe",
         "description": "Description",
         "date": "2021-03-07",
         "time": "18:44:21",
         "usuario": {
           "id": "a391dc7f-33af-4798-a41c-374a06f2f73e",
           "nome": "usuario"
         }
       }
     ]
   }
 ]
}
```

Please, someone help me!

Answer (score 0):

To get the last interaction of a ticket you need to join `ticket` with `ticket_interactions` using a subquery.

Something like this-

```
createQueryBuilder('ticket')
.leftJoin(`(SELECT id FROM ticket_interactions order by createdAt DESC limit 1)`, 'latestTicketInteraction', 'ticket.id = latestTicketInteraction.id')
.leftJoin('users', 'users', 'users.id = ticket_interactions.user_id')
.select('ticket.id', 'id')
.addSelect('latestTicketInteraction.id', 'latestTicketInteractionId')
.getRawOne()
```

You need to substitute table names and column names according to table structure and add the respective attributes in the `SELECT` clause.